# Split flange for converter-resonator coupling?

Tags: chevrolet, exhaust, cavalier

'04 Cavalier.  The converter outlet coupling failed - the bolts broke,
and the bolt holes in both flanges are pretty much useless.  Given the
age of the car, and the cost of replacing all the components, I
thought to use a couple of split flanges instead.  But, I'm having a
lot of trouble finding the right sized flanges.  The original flanges
are '3-bolt', as is the gasket - http://shop.advanceautoparts.com/p/walker-exhaust-gasket-31369/18370047-P

The problem is, finding the flanges.  The pipe measures 2" O.D.  There are
a lot of 2-bolt 2" split flanges, but 3-bolt ones seem rare, while other
sizes seem much more common.  Nothing local.  I did find a 2" one
online http://exhaustdirect.com/FFS200-3.html

The scarcity makes me wonder if I'm just missing something.  I
mean, it's a Cavalier - usually, anything I need is readily available.

Any thoughts/experience would be appreciated.  (Especially, if this is
just not going to work, and I should just bite the bullet and replace
the converter & resonator/mid-pipe.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to replace it the way you are suggesting, why not do it a little easier with a V-Flange split coupler. Something like this:

[image: Image pulled from Summit Racing]

(NOTE: This is just an example from [Summit Racing](http://www.summitracing.com/parts/vpe-1488/overview/) You can find them on eBay all day long.)

Each side of the split would fit, one on the cat and one on the exhaust pipe. You'd need to weld these in place. They seal *very well* and you'd not have to worry about a seal as these self seal once the band clamp is in place.